# Join method in C# and java

Tags: c#, java

I want to join a "timeout" to a thread! I have the java code and I want to convert it to C#...

```
 try {
     deLog.thread.join(DeLog.getTimeout());
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {}
```

Seems that there is a method called Join in C#, but when I change the join in the code to the Join I get error.

What is the best way of joining a timeout to a thread in C#?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This is not joining timeout to a thread. This is joining to the current thread with a given timeout.

So this is blocking the current thread until `deLog.thread` terminates or until the specified timeout is elapsed.

See also here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: My explanation was not so good :) I knew that what I wanna do is to joining a timeout to the current thread